# If the <div> Element Is Block Level Element How Could 2 divs Be Placed Next to Each Other

Tags: html

According to w3schools.com I learnt that the  element is a block level element (that is, the browser will display a line break before and after it).

Then how could 2 divs be placed next to each other?

**Some code from w3schools:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <body>

         <div id="container" style="width:500px">

            <div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
               <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Main Title of Web Page</h1>
         </div>

         <div id="menu" style="background color:#FFD700;height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
            <b>Menu</b><br>
            HTML<br>
            CSS<br>
            JavaScript
         </div>

         <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">Content goes here
         </div>

         <div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">Copyright © W3Schools.com
         </div>

         </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: please see this site: http://w3fools.com

Comment: and look into css float

Comment: and absolute positioning and also changing the display type to something else like inline-block... really depends on what you need in your layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"By default, block-level elements are formatted differently than inline elements. Generally, block-level elements begin on new lines, inline elements do not."

Two block level elements will generally start on new lines, but you can have them side by side by `float` property. In your code, you have this piece in the div style which is making them side by side.

```
float: left;
```

Comment: NO. stop passing links to w3schools. http://w3fools.com

Comment: alright just google css float and learn the ins and out of float, since it's very useful. If you're learning positioning, I think lynda's css positioning tutorial can be a great starting point too.

Comment: Thank you. I am aiming to study CSS next.

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebyside">I'm stuff!</div>
<div class="sidebyside">I'm other stuff!</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebyside {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/VM93v/)

Comment: thank you I already know how to position them side by side I just got confused because they say that the browser displays a break line before and (after) it.

Comment: OP explicitly asks "how could 2 divs be placed next to each other?" I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google for "side by side div" yielded this as the first result, and a bunch more too!

http://www.welovecss.com/showthread.php?t=465

Comment: This seems more like a comment.